# ACTION_DOWN is detected but not ACTION_UP? android gridView item's onTouch

Tags: android, gridview

I want to remove a gridView item's shadow when the user presses it, and then restore it once the user releases.  (cant use selector.xml because items have a user chosen color)

this code removes shadow when first pressed but upon release it stays stuck down with no shadow.

```
gridItemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                image.removeShadow();
                image.invalidate();
            }
            else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                image.setShadow();
                image.invalidate();

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I cant set it to true, because then .OnItemClickListener in the fragment dosent work.  Also I kinda fixed it by setting the shadow to turn on in onItemClickListener, but if the user slides their thumb off the item instead of just clicking it will stay pressed

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            MainActivity.selectedItem = position;
            if (lastView[0] != null) {
                lastView[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nullr);
            }
            picker.setOldCenterColor(MainActivity.items.get(MainActivity.selectedItem).getColor());
            picker.setColor(MainActivity.items.get(MainActivity.selectedItem).getColor());

            View imageContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.imageContainer);
            CircularImageView circleImage = (CircularImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.circleView);

            artistText.setText(MainActivity.items.get(position).getArtist());
            songText.setText(MainActivity.items.get(position).getSong());

            int backgroundColor = Color.parseColor("#FFEECC");
            GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{backgroundColor, backgroundColor});
            drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
            drawable.setStroke(25, MainActivity.items.get(MainActivity.selectedItem).getColor());

            imageContainer.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            circleImage.setShadow();
            circleImage.invalidate();

            lastView[0] = imageContainer;
            MainActivity.anItemIsSelected = true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot

```
else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            image.setShadow();
            image.invalidate();
}
```

what you can do here is try to create a custom `Gridview` and override onTouchEvent, something like this, (it is not precisely accurate though)

```
public class MyGridv extends GridView{
    //implement all constructors;
    //the override onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event);
    @override
    protected boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    // put your ontouch code here and return true, you might need to do
     //some changes because you can not get access to your methods or 
     //you can make this class a private class to your mainActivity
     // now delete your ontouch for your gridview
    }
   }
```

the logic here is `onTouchEvent()` is initially called before your `onTouchListener`and its the first to be called, returning true there will then pass the event to `onTouch()` and on `onClick`, there everything will work fine

hope its helpful

Comment: thx but i had it like that before, and tried switch statement too, it still dosent work and stays shadow removed

Comment: Note when i return true it works, but i cant return true because onItemClick dosent work then

Comment: check my edit that i am about to make, i am making a rough solution,as i am not on android now.@TintinabulatorZea

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below on your View.

```
android:clickable="true"
```